# In Postman, is there a way to persist request body values (as environment values)?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am trying to chain a couple of API requests together and wanted to automate the values to be carried over in the chain. Request body for first request looks something like this

```
{
   :
   :
   "details":{
      "identifiers":[
          {
            "id": "1234", // ---> Am setting this manually, which I need in my 2nd request.
            "idType": "SpecialID"
          },
          {
             "id": "3456",
             "idType": "uninterestingID"

          }

       ]

    }

}
```

Note that

- I want to use the value of ***id*** in the second request only if it is of ***idType*** "SpecialID"
- The order of these two IDs may not be fixed
- In some requests, "uninteresting" ID may not be sent BUT "SpecialID" will always be sent

Given the above conditions, how do I do this in a Postman test i.e. store the value of id in the request body of one API call and use that in a second API's request call ? If customer code is required, I don't see a way to do this in Postman.

Comment: You can use pre request script in postman

Comment: I have also used environment variables, and in the test of one request, postman.setEnvironmentVariable('Key', jsonData[0].Key); to save a variable for use in another test (typically next one) with a getEnvironmentVariable. You can also use these in the URL using the braces notation.  DELETE /api/alerts/{{Key}}

Comment: I'm not quite following this work flow. You have an hardcoded ID of 1234 against the idType "SpecialID". This is in the request, not the response.  Why can't you just change the value of this element in the body of both requests to be the same variable? You say it will always get sent, therefore the element should exist in the request body of both requests.

Comment: @mikee - Yes, it exists in both requests but if I cannot chain them because say I run the first API with, say, id:  "1234" (hardcoded as I need a random value). I have used environment values so that the params, for the second API is populated after first API's respoonse. But I still have to hardcode that id: "1234" in second API. What I want is that after first API is run, I don't need to do any manual updated to the second API's request body.

Comment: But why can't you use an environment variable with the value, and use the same environment variable in request 1 and 2.  I don't get why it needs to be hardcoded in request 1.  If you update the environment variable, it will be used for both requests.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I can define the "run" variable as say "id": {{runId}} and change it before the run. Using that same variable in multiple places will use the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get the id from the object with the idType of "SpecialID" within the request body and save it to an environment variable, you can do the following.

```js
let body = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);

let specialID = (body.details.identifiers.find(obj => { return obj.idType === 'SpecialID' })).id

pm.environment.set("id", specialID);
console.log(pm.environment.get("id")); // 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used postman environment variables between tests.  My test creates a single Alert, and then I want to get it, validate it returns what would have been saved, then delete the alert.

POST /api/Alerts {}

[image: GET /api/Alerts]

The Test can then validate results and create environment variables for the next tests.

```
pm.test("Response should be 200", function () { 
    pm.response.to.be.ok;
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

const jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.length).greaterThan(0);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('Alert_Key', jsonData[0].Key_);
```

I can then send a DELETE with the environment variable in the URL using brace syntax.

[image: DELETE {{TimeSheetAPI}}/api/alerts/{{Alert_Key}}]

I have also used the tests to simply loop through all the returned values, and call DELETE routes as well.

```
pm.test("Response should be 200", function () { 
    pm.response.to.be.ok;
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test("Parse Alert Key_ values and send DELETE", function () {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    jsonData.forEach(function (AlertRecord) {
        console.log(AlertRecord.Key_);
        const DeleteURL = pm.variables.get('TimeSheetAPI') + '/api/alerts/' + AlertRecord.Key_;
        pm.sendRequest({
            url: DeleteURL, 
            method: 'DELETE',
            header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: '{ "Key_": ' + AlertRecord.Key_ + '} ' }
        , function (err, res) {
            console.log("Sent Delete: " + DeleteURL );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, but what does this have to do with original posters question?

Comment: Sample of how to carry data over between requests.  Using the environment variables allows the OP to persist data for later use.

Comment: @StevenScott - I clarified my question. I missed mentioning (sorry) that I need a property value in the request body to be ported between APIs . The two APIs are chained - API A and API B (say), I run API A with id: 123 (manual input). I am already capturing API A's response json elements and updating the relevant input to API B's url params. However. I am still having to update the request body for API B manually with the  id = '1234' before I can run it. I want to be able to update that automatically as well

Comment: @user1554876 If they are in sequence (calling order) you can use the environment variables in the request body, the same was the URL, using the double braces `{{your_value}}`. It needs to be formatted for the request (quoted if a string, etc.).